# Web apps that generate nice photo/video galleries by recursively searching directories

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, perl, photos, photo-gallery

I am going to upload all of my photos to an Apache web server - they're all in folders & sub-folders. Filenames are not descriptive and I don't care about the meta data.

I've worked with PHP Gallery before, but find the process of creating albums, etc. a little laborious. I just want to rsync my local photo folders with my web site.

Is there some PHP/Perl/RoR script/app that I can configure by pointing to a folder and telling it to generate a decent looking photo gallery automatically? If it has to talk to MySQL - that'd be fine too. As long as it's a one-time config on installation. I could live with having to automatically reindex or something with a daily cron.

I'm just looking for a bunch of suggestions. I don't need anything fancy i.e. no tagging, slideshows, etc. (although that'd be nice). It's primarily for my parents to see photos of their grandson - some thumbnails and a navbar would work!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Zen Photo](http://www.zenphoto.org/). It can read directories and generates albums based on the directory names.

Although it brings some of the more "web-two-zeroy" functions, it still performs the first things you mention brilliantly. It also brings customisable themes, etc.

Comment: Thanks - installed it just there; don't see any (obvious) way to create galleries from directories on the server though. Do I need a plugin?

Thanks again,

Comment: Ah, nevermind - I guess I just need to use *their* photo directory... it doesn't appear to be configurable..